# UICollectionView - groups

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

This is just a conceptual question about UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.

I am working on an app that has a view in it that is very similar to the AppStore's "All Reviews" page and I am planning on implementing this with a compositional layout, but I am just confused about what to make the group be.

Here is the page in the AppStore app that I am talking about.

[image: Apple AppStore Reviews page]

I was looking at the documentation for compositional layout and noticed this picture. At first glance, the top section is similar to what I want except that it scrolls horizontally rather than vertically. I am just curious why the group is around each item in this image. What is the benefit of having the group around each item, or having all the items in one group?

The way I understand it from the WWDC videos and the documentation is that a group is (conceptually at least) similar to a flow layout. So I am just curious if it would be better in this example here to have all of the items in one group (one flow layout) or to have separate groups for each item, like they do in this image.

And what are the tradeoffs or deciding factors when determining which items go in a group? I have seen some of the examples from the WWDC videos where they have a grid layout, and each row is a separate group. But if a group is similar to flow layout, couldn't all the items be in one group?

I guess I am just confused about groups and when to use one group for all the items or when to split the items into multiple groups.

[image: Apple documentation on Compositional Layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just curious why the group is around each item in this image

In my opinion, the image is just a small sketch of the compositional layout

the top section one group has one `item` (not `NSCollectionLayoutItem`) or `cell`, but the bottom group has three `items`

Consider the code in Apple example [Implementing Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) `EmojiExplorerViewController`:

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize) 
item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5) 
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.28), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2)) 
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item]) 
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
```

the group has subItems `item`, items count is decided by `NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot` count

in the Xcode View hierarchy, you cannot see any view except cells and some small necessary views

There is no view named `xxxGroupView`

Don't overthink, so be simple first.

> What is the benefit of having the group around each item, or having all the items in one group?

Do what you want to do, if one group can have all items, why not. A simpler compositional layout may have more efficient

> what are the tradeoffs or deciding factors when determining which items go in a group

separate items into groups when you have to.

look again the  `OrthogonalScrollingViewController` in the [Implementing Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views)

```
//   +-----------------------------------------------------+
//   | +---------------------------------+  +-----------+  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | |                                 |  |     1     |  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | |                                 |  +-----------+  |
//   | |               0                 |                 |
//   | |                                 |  +-----------+  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | |                                 |  |     2     |  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | |                                 |  |           |  |
//   | +---------------------------------+  +-----------+  |
//   +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

```
let leadingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.7),
                                                  heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)))
leadingItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

let trailingItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                                  heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.3)))
trailingItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
let trailingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.3),
                                                  heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)), subitem: trailingItem, count: 2)

let containerGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
                layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.85),
                                                  heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.4)),
                subitems: [leadingItem, trailingGroup])
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: containerGroup)
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
return section
```